# BUILDROOT and PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, buildroot

Hello I'm having problems with buildroot and enabled option for python-pyqt5.
I used default config for raspberry pi4 and added the Qt5 support and Python-PyQt5.
Compiling with only PyQt5 is ok but if I enable Python-pyqt5 it fails.
Does anyone else have this problem?
I cross-compiled on two different machines running Linux Mint and the problem is on both of them. It seem that when compiling siplib.c there is a problem.

```
siplib.c: In function ‘sip_api_get_frame’:
siplib.c:13750:22: error: invalid use of undefined type ‘struct _frame’
13750 |         frame = frame->f_back;
      |                      ^~
```